# regex unable to match string

Tags: php, regex

I am unablt to use the following code to match the following string, I do not know what is going on

```
$regex = "/\\251/i";
if (preg_match($regex, $contents)) {
  echo 'good it works';
}
```

the $contents are as follows

`Shanghai Taipei Tokyo TorontoOxford is a registered trade mark of Oxford University Pressin the UK and in certain other countriesPublished in the United Statesby Oxford University Press Inc., New YorkRevised text \251 John Guy 2000`

I have tried encoding the string to no luck

```
$contents = utf8_encode ($contents);
```

this works in all the online tools i used, am I missing anything to see why it would not work when being run?

Comment: Do you want to match `\251` in string ?

Comment: Make sure you don't have a typo for `$regex` & `$regext`.

Comment: yes i do the following works on this website but not when ranhttp://www.phpliveregex.com/

Comment: How are you establishing the value of `contents`? Are you escaping the \ there as well?

Comment: yes sorry edited to account for that variables are the same

Comment: @PeterAlfvin no the \ is not escaped, i am parsing an url and returning it as an string

Answer (score 0):

In this case want to use the raw (unescaped) backslash to match the character `251` (Character octal 0251 is the [ISO-LATIN-1 copyright symbol](http://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?utf8=oct)).

Try simply `\251` to match the © character directly, since it looks like your content is already UTF8 encoded.

See an example: http://regex101.com/r/eT3mZ8

Answer (score 0):

You should try with:

```
preg_match('/(\xA9)/i', $text);
```

Or:

```
preg_match('/(\251)/i', $text);
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried in PERL to check whether regex is proper or not. Please find the following perl code which has regex which perfectly matches \251

```
#!C:\Perl64\bin
$regex = "Shanghai Taipei Tokyo TorontoOxford is a registered trade mark of Oxford University Pressin the UK and in certain other countriesPublished in the United Statesby Oxford University Press Inc., New YorkRevised text \251 John Guy 2000";
if ("$regex" =~ m/(\251)/)
{
    print "Success scenario\n";
    print "$regex is matched \n";
} else {
    print "$regex is not matched \n";
}
```

This will output -->

```
Success scenario
Shanghai Taipei Tokyo TorontoOxford is a registered trade mark of Oxford Univers
```

ity Pressin the UK and in certain other countriesPublished in the United Statesb
y Oxford University Press Inc., New YorkRevised text \251 John Guy 2000 is matched

Hope this might help you

Thanks